# Inheriting from a class which doesn't exist in Python

Tags: python, import

So what I'm trying to do is, running a piece of code in multiple environments. In the environment(s) where the module is present, I can inherit the class from it, but where the module isn't present, I don't want my code to break and an error shouldn't come.

```
try:
    from school.modules import student
except ImportError:
    pass

class MyWebAPP(student.StudentClass):
```

I get an error that student isn't defined. I want to somehow by-pass this.
Suggestions ?

Comment: If import is success set a variable as True and only when that value is true, use the imported class/module. Otherwise don't do it. Curious to know, What is your failover if student import fails?

Comment: How is your class going to make use of maybe inheriting from another class? What good does that do you?

Comment: @Vikash- As i said the code is intended to be used in MULTIPLE environments, in environments where the module isn't present, we don't intend to use it at all, hence the class from the module should not be inherited. That's the so called "failover".

Comment: @khelwood - There could be interfaces present in that class which I wan't do define in my own class :)

Comment: @CodePlorer But whatever is present in the base class is stuff you can't use in your code because the base class might be missing.

Comment: @khelwood You can take the presumption that in environments where the class wouldn't be found, we wouldn't require usage of the interface as well. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: @CodePlorer All right, I'll presume you know what you're doing.

Comment: @khelwood- Thanks, as a closing comment, think of situations where you are inheriting from multiple classes. You need to add, lets say only 1 additional feature, for a specific environment where that class is available. Rest of the 9 features would still work fine by inheriting from other base class(es) in other environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the class to a variable and use `object` in case it doesn't exist.

```
try:
    from school.modules import student
    parent = student.StudentClass
except ImportError:
    parent = object

class MyWebAPP(parent):
    pass
```

This prevents that you have to repeat the whole definition of the class in both branches, but assumes that everything else inside the class doesn't need changes depending on the base class that is used.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!